# After upgrading AIR sdk from 3.1 to 4.0 started missing spark.transitions package

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

By following [this](http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2010/11/02/installing-the-air-sdk-on-flash-builder/) tutorial I upgraded AIR sdk from 3.1 to 4.0, however now I am getting compile time errors that

```
import spark.transitions.ViewTransitionBase;
```

**The import transitions could not be found.**

So it seems like spark.transitions.* just disappeared, if I download AIR sdk 3.1 and put it back, everything starts working again.

**EDIT**:

The same thing happened to `spark.components.ViewNavigator`, I can't use it in my project anymore.

Did anyhow have this problem and what are possible best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't overlay the AIR SDK. You simply overwrote it. So it deleted all of the Flex files, too. Easiest fix is to just reinstall it all. Grab the Flex installer from http://flex.apache.org. It will let you choose which versions of both Flex and AIR to install.

Comment: hm.. that's what I thought, how do I overlay it properly?

Comment: Depends on what system you are using. On OS X, I use the `ditto` command.

Comment: it's Windows, is there anything similar?

Comment: I'm unsure. I'm not overly familiar with Windows commands. I tend to work with Unix-based systems.

Comment: I am going to use the installer that you've recommended and accept your answer! :)